# Wide equalizers

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, terminology

If $(f_i : A \to B)_{i \in I}$ is a family of morphisms in a category, we may declare their *wide equalizer* as a universal morphism $\iota : E \to A$ which satisfies $f_i \iota = f_j \iota$ for all $i,j \in I$. Usually one restricts to the case $I=\{1,2\}$. I wonder if this generalization is known and if the term "wide equalizer" is common. Similarly for "wide coequalizer". The notions of "wide pullback" and "wide pushout" are well-established. Notice that "wide equalizers" are used in the proof of Freyd's criterion for initial objects (and hence, in Freyd's adjoint functor theorem). A typical example is the kernel of a group action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling for [equalizer family morphisms](http://www.google.com/search?q=equalizer+family+morphisms)
(also in [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?q=equalizer+family+morphisms) and [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=equalizer+family+morphisms)) returned some hits. 
It seems that some people use the name *[multiple equalizer](http://www.google.com/search?q=category+morphisms+%22multiple+equalizer%22)*.

Adámek, Herrlich, Strecker: [Abstract and Concrete Categories. The Joy of Cats](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf) mention this notion in Example 11.4(2), p. 194. Another book using this notion is 
Castellini: Categorical Closure Operators, see [p.12](http://books.google.com/books?id=LA8VajAiQ5UC&pg=PA12).